# Throwing null pointerException in Timer.Schedule();

Tags: java, android, multithreading, timer, timertask

In the following code
**t.schedule(timertask, d.getDate(), 1000);** is throwing 
**NullPointer exception**
help me out

**Goal :**
My basic goal is to **Run** a method(**every time after a fixed interval** ) that will **send** some data to **webservice from my android device**

```
Date d = new Date();
    d.getDate();
    timertask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Thread() {

                public void run() {
                    try {
                        ProDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Home.this,
                                "Sending Data",
                                "Please wait while sending data...");
                        Looper.prepare();
                        sendLocation();
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                        quit();
                        Looper.loop();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        ProDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }

                public void quit() {
                    ProDialog.dismiss();
                    Looper.myLooper().quit();
                }
            }.start();
        }
    };
try {
    t.schedule(timertask, d.getDate(), 1000);
} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You might have not initialized all your variables .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initialize your

> t

first.

Change

```
try {
        t.schedule(timertask, d.getDate(), 1000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

To

```
try 
 {
    Timer t=new Timer();
    t.schedule(timertask, d.getDate(), 1000);
 } 
catch (Exception e) 
 {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: or may do this :  try {
        timertask .schedule(timertask, d.getDate(), 1000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

Answer (score 1):

Basically `NullPointerException` throws where the required object is `null`.

The reasons for `NullPointerException`

- Calling the instance method of a null object.
- Accessing or modifying the field of a null object.
- Taking the length of null as if it were an array.
- Accessing or modifying the slots of null as if it were an array.
- Throwing null as if it were a Throwable value.
- Applications should throw instances of this class to indicate other illegal uses of 
  the null object.

Explained in this link more eloborately [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception)